# Why is this overflow property being ignored on nested divs?

Tags: css

In the example below I would expect the `content` divs to be scrollable but the property is being ignored, why is this and how do I fix it?

I know that if I remove the `overflow-y` property from the outer `div` then the whole page will scroll vertically, but I want/expect the individual columns to scroll. It appears from the borders that they should do this.

This may be due to some odd flexbox related behaviour that I am unaware of, but I haven't been able to work out what it could be?

```
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
.columns {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid #00ff00;
}

.column {
  flex: 0 0 320px;
  border: 1px solid #008800;
}

.header h4 {
  margin: 3px 0;
}

.content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.mention {
  background: rgba(147, 128, 108, .1);
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class='columns'>
  <div class='column'>
    <div class='header'><h4>Header</h2></div>
    <div class='content'>
      <div class='mention'>Lorem ipsum...</div>
      <div class='mention'>Lorem ipsum...</div>
      <div class='mention'>Lorem ipsum...</div>
      <div class='mention'>Lorem ipsum...</div>
      <div class='mention'>Lorem ipsum...</div>
      <div class='mention'>Lorem ipsum...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='column'>
    <div class='header'><h4>Header</h2></div>
    <div class='content'>
      <div class='mention'>Lorem ipsum...</div>
      <div class='mention'>Lorem ipsum...</div>
      <div class='mention'>Lorem ipsum...</div>
      <div class='mention'>Lorem ipsum...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This you can try:

```
.content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid blue;
    height:400px;
}
```

[**Take a look**](http://jsfiddle.net/umfj0htz/)

Comment: That would work, but the height of the content is dynamic, in the actual app there are a variable number of `mention` elements and the height of each of them can also vary based on content.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `height: 100%;` to both the `column` and `content` classes did the trick.